# Find threads for chat

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have problem with find old thread for my chat. 
It's have table like

```
#  id              :bigint(8)       
#  user_id         :bigint(8)
#  thread_id :bigint(8)
```

Each thread have 2 user_id and thread_id  (that same) And problem is with searching - I have array with users [12,22,555], and now i need to find thread id where all users exist. How ?

Comment: Please show us your datamodel, in more detail. I can assume you have a `User` model, a `Thread` model, but how are they linked? How are your relations set up? Then your question is: how to find a common thread (group-chat?) of a given array of users, right?

Comment: Yes, its User model and Thread model - they are linked by UserThreads model.

Comment: Exactly - find a common thread of a given array of users. - Only thread where all users get discussion

Comment: Anyone can help ?